# NullPointerException where there shouldn't be one

Tags: java

So I'm getting a NullPointerException on line 17 and 19 of this code.

```
package Commands;

import Engine.Command;
import Engine.GameObject;
import Engine.ItemObject;
import Engine.RoomObject;

public class East implements Command {

    int pY = GameObject.pY;
    int pX = GameObject.pX;

    RoomObject[][] m = GameObject.m;

    @Override
    public void execute(String cmd) {
        if (m[pY][pX+1].canEnter == true) {
            pX+=1;
            System.out.println(m[pY][pX].name);
            showItems();
        } else { System.out.println("Can't move."); }
    }

    public void showItems() {
        System.out.println("Items you can see:");
        if (m[pY][pX].inv.size() >= 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m[pY][pX].inv.size(); i++) {
                ItemObject tempObject = m[pY][pX].inv.get(i);
                System.out.println(tempObject.name);
            }
        } else { System.out.println("No items here."); }
    }
}
```

There shouldn't be a nullpointer there at all because it was working fine before I started using different classes for all my commands.

This is for a text adventure game engine.

EDIT: the culprit is

```
RoomObject[][] m = GameObject.m;
```

But I have no idea why :/

Comment: see this debugger tutorial -> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: The first thing you do when you get a NullPointerException is to find out what's null. The second, and often easy, step, is to find out why. You're rushing things. Here's a train of thought: _It's null, I guess the coordinates are wrong somehow. Yep, they were._ :p

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but maybe you want `pX` to be initialized as

```
int pX = GameObject.pX;
```

Comment: Hahaha, I'm dumb, Probably should have read more of my code before posting. Thank you :) I've been up for 12 hours coding this thign.

Comment: I've done some more testing and found it's not entirely that, It seems `RoomObject[][] m = GameObject.m;` isn't working at all.

Comment: You maybe want to look inside GameObject class for that.

Comment: Looked into it, right after the game initializes I print out the room name with `System.out.println(m[pY][pX].name);` And it works fine, also a command I put in called "look" seems to work and does the exact same thing, except this time it returns the default name of the room instead of the name I set in a before any of this is even run. I don't think it likes the `pX+1` weird :/

Comment: Are you sure you want `m[pY][pX]` and not `m[pX][pY]`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. I just fixed it. I have to set pY and pX inside my execute method. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: You might want to accept the answer if it helped. :)